# Absence of discontinuity in Specific Heat in liquid-gas transition (Based on the Ising Model)

Tags: computational-physics, c, monte-carlo

I'm trying to do a model for the transition liquid-gas based on the Ising model and the metropolis algorithm, instead of using values of spins, I'm saying that a cell is occupied by a particle or not. My specific heat doesn't show a discontinuity and I'm struggling to find the problem. I have tried to increase the size of my lattice, the numbers of sweeps and also to decrease the steps that I do to change temperature.The Montecarlo function works as followed :

1.We choose randomly a cell, if it's occupied we choose one of its neighbors

2.If the neighbor is occupied we do nothing

3.If it's not we calculate the energy of the lattice and then we made the particle jump to the second cell

4.We then calculate the energy in this configuration

5.We do the metropolis algorithm as for the Ising model : if conditions are not met we reverse back to the 1st configuration and if they are we add dE to the energy.

To calculate the energy I'm using the same expression as for the Ising Model, which means that if a particles as its 4 nearest neighbors occupied the energy of this site will be 4. And we are going to count like this the number of nearest neighbors site occupied for every site.

To calculate the heat capacity I'm trying to use this equation :
$C=\big[\langle E^2\rangle-\langle E\rangle^2\big]/k_BT^2$
I have also tried to zoom in around 1~3 and the heat capacity only decreases and show 0 discontinuity

Here are my plot for the energy and heat capacity vs temperature with parameter that are in the code :
[image]
[image]
Here is my code :

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <math.h>


#define L 40            /*Lattice size*/
#define STEPS 10000     /*Numbers of step to obtain equilibrium*/
#define mol 1000        /*Numbers of particles in the system*/
#define J 1             /*Value of the interaction*/
#define T_MIN 0.1       /*Minimal temperature*/
#define T_MAX 7         /*Maximal temperature*/
#define T_STEP 0.08
#define kB 1

double energy;
int N[L][L];



void display();                          
void init_params();                     
double calc_energy();                   
void MonteCarlo(double temperature);    
void save();                            
 /*This is the main function that will do the calculation for the energy and heat_capacity vs temperature*/
int main() {
    FILE *file1, *file2 ;
    file1 = fopen("energy.dat","w");
    file2 = fopen("heat_capacity.dat","w");

    double temperature;
    for (temperature = T_MIN; temperature <= T_MAX; temperature += T_STEP) {
/*at each temperature we initialize the lattice*/
        init_params();
/*calculate the energy and energy squared and initialize the heat capacity*/ 
        energy = calc_energy(); 
        double en = energy;
        double energy_squared = energy * energy;
        double heat_capacity = 0.0;
/* here we are going to do a lot of steps of the function Monte Carlo to obtain equilibrium and to be able to calculate a mean of energy*/
        for (int step = 0; step < STEPS; step ++){ 
            MonteCarlo(temperature);
            en += energy;
            energy_squared += energy * energy;

        }
        en /=(STEPS*L*L);
        energy_squared /= (STEPS*L*L) ;
        heat_capacity = (energy_squared - en*en)/(kB * temperature*temperature);
/*Saving up the quantities into file to graph them*/
        fprintf(file1,"%lf %lf \n",temperature,en);
        fprintf(file2,"%lf %lf \n",temperature,heat_capacity);

    }
}
/*Initialization of the lattice*/
void init_params() {
    time_t *tm=NULL;
    srand48(time(tm));
    int k=0;
    int a,b;
/*First of all we made it completely empty*/
    for(int i = 0; i < L; i++) { 
        for(int j = 0; j < L; j++) {
            N[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
/* and then we randomly fill it with the number of particles choose before*/
    while (k<mol) {                       
        a = floor(drand48()*L);  
        b = floor(drand48()*L);   
        if(N[a][b]==0) {                 
            N[a][b]= 1;
            k++;                       
        }    
     }
} 
/* This is the function that calculate the energy of the lattice with cyclic boundaries, its the same expression as the Ising Model*/
double calc_energy() {
    double energy = 0.0;
    int i,j;
    for(i = 0; i < L; i++) {         
        for(j = 0; j < L; j++) {     
            int up = (i == 0 ? L-1 : i-1);
            int down = (i == L-1 ? 0 : i+1);
            int left = (j == 0 ? L-1 : j-1);
            int right = (j == L-1 ? 0 : j+1);
            energy += -J*N[i][j]*(N[up][j]+N[down][j]+N[i][left]+N[i][right]);
        }
    }

    return energy/2.0;
}
/*This is the function that will do the MonteCarlo and Metropolis algorithm*/
void MonteCarlo(double temperature) {
    int n,ix,iy,N_init;
    double E1, E2, dE;
    int a,b;
    double p,r;
  /*We are choosing one random site on the lattice*/  
    ix = floor(drand48()*L);
    iy = floor(drand48()*L);
    N_init = N[ix][iy];
/*If it's occupied we can do the rest of the code*/
    if (N_init == 1) { 
/*Here we are choosing one of its neighbors randomly*/ 
        n = floor(drand48()*4);
        if (n == 0) {
            a = (ix + L - 1) % L;
            b = iy;
        } 
        else if (n == 1) {
            a = ix;
            b = (iy + 1) % L;
        } 
        else if (n == 2) {
            a = (ix + 1) % L;
            b = iy;
        } 
        else { 
            a= ix;
            b = (iy + L - 1) % L;
        }
/*Calculation of the energy of the lattice before a swap*/            
        E1 = calc_energy(); 
/*If the neighbor site is empty we are going to jump the particle from the first site to it*/
        if (N[a][b] == 0){
            N[ix][iy] = 0;
            N[a][b] = 1;
/*We calculate the energy of the new lattice after the jump and make the metropolis algorithm like for the ising model.*/
            E2 = calc_energy();
            dE = E2 - E1;
            p = exp(-dE/(kB*temperature));
            r = drand48();
/*If the condition are not met we return to the first lattice and the energy of the system is E1*/
            if ((dE>0) && (p<r)){
                        N[ix][iy] = 1;
                        N[a][b] = 0;
                        energy = E1;
            }
/*If conditions are met we keep the lattice as it is and have the energy E2 for our system*/
            else {energy = E2;}

        

        }
            
    }   
}
```

Comment: Your code has 140 lines but not one comment. Your plots have axes but no labels. You will need to get better at describing what you are doing and seeing if you hope that others will volunteer their time to help you.

Comment: Ho okei, my bad, I though describing it in words was sufficient sorry. Im going to add comments :)